# why std::istringstream fail when I set std::locale to "zh_CN.UTF-8"?

Tags: c++, c++11

the code is as follow:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <sstream>

int main() 
{
    std::locale::global(std::locale("zh_CN.UTF-8"));

    std::string str = u8"8086";
    std::istringstream iss(str);
    int e;
    iss >> e;
    if (iss.fail())
    {
        std::cout<<"failed  "<<"e = "<<e<<std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And the output is:

```
failed  e = 8086
```

The `operator>>` is successful but why does `fail()` return true?

---

**I tried it in centos7 and `fail()` returned `false`, but when I run it in macOS, `fail()` returns `true`? Why?**

---------------------- Environment -------------------

```
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Comment: I tried running this on some machines onlines, and they get run time error that the locale doesn't exist. What's the configuration on your machine?

Comment: do your matchines support c++11? or forget to set this flag?

Comment: I use the mac mini

Comment: You'd better specify not only OS, but also your compiler and library, or at least the IDE.

Answer (score 3):

This is a [libc++ bug](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=28704). It enforces to check the position of grouping characters even if there is no grouping character in the number.

For now, you can add grouping characters to fix this issue, i.e. use `"8,086"` instead.